# Can SublimeText2 key bindings map to package commands, like "SublimeREPL:Ruby"?

Tags: sublimetext2, key-bindings

I'm trying to create a key binding for opening a SublimeREPL:Ruby window in ST2, but am not sure if you can create shortcuts for non-basic commands.

I've searched around http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/key_bindings.html and googled my little heart out but can't find anything about creating key bindings for foreign packages.

On 2nd thought (I'm a 1y/o dev) - I decided to browse package files. I found this in `/Users/administrator/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/SublimeREPL/config/Ruby`:

```
[
 {
    "id": "tools",
    "children":
    [{
        "caption": "SublimeREPL",
        "mnemonic": "r",
        "id": "SublimeREPL",
        "children":
        [
            {"command": "repl_open", 
             "caption": "Ruby",
             "id": "repl_ruby",
             "mnemonic": "r",
             "args": {
                "type": "subprocess",
                "external_id": "ruby",
                "encoding": "utf8",
                "cmd": {"windows": ["irb.bat", "--noreadline", "--inf-ruby-mode"],
                        "linux": ["irb", "--noreadline", "--inf-ruby-mode"],
                        "osx": ["irb", "--noreadline", "--inf-ruby-mode"]},
                "soft_quit": "\nexit\n",
                "cwd": "$file_path",
                "cmd_postfix": "\n", // postfix 
                "suppress_echo": true,
                "syntax": "Packages/Ruby/Ruby.tmLanguage"
                }
            }
        ]   
    }]
}
]
```

I created the key binding:`{ "keys": ["super+i", "super+r", "super+b"], "command": "repl_open" }`

But no dice. Any ideas? Restart ST2 maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define the shortcut key, you should supply the `repl_open` command the arguments it got in the declaration of the menu item you provided.

Try the following (not tested, but very similar to the configuration I have for another environment in REPL):

```
{ "keys": ["super+i", "super+r", "super+b"], "command": "repl_open", "args":
   {
        "type": "subprocess",
        "external_id": "ruby",
        "encoding": "utf8",
        "cmd": {"windows": ["irb.bat", "--noreadline", "--inf-ruby-mode"],
            "linux": ["irb", "--noreadline", "--inf-ruby-mode"],
            "osx": ["irb", "--noreadline", "--inf-ruby-mode"]},
        "soft_quit": "\nexit\n",
        "cwd": "$file_path",
        "cmd_postfix": "\n", // postfix 
        "suppress_echo": true,
        "syntax": "Packages/Ruby/Ruby.tmLanguage"
   }
}
```

A simpler option (but less configurable) is just to call the menu item directly (again, not tested but similar to my configuration):

```
{ "keys": ["super+i", "super+r", "super+b"],
  "command": "run_existing_window_command", "args":
    {
        "id": "repl_ruby",
        "file": "config/Ruby/Main.sublime-menu"
    }
},
```